# Bootstrap position absolute a link in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some content inside a bootstrap column. I need to position the link within the Textarea like below.

[image]

and the link also should consist Its position even though the text area is resized horizontally or vertically. How can I achieve this with jquery or CSS ?

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b359go1c/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Record Feedback" role="button" class="recorded-feedback-modal">Link</a>    
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" spellcheck="false"></textarea>    
    <p>Test Content</p>
    <p>Test Content</p>
    <p>Test Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.recorded-feedback-modal {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x3rfk926/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a relative container around `textarea` and link that is `inline-block`
- Position link absolutely inside of container

[image]

```css
.textarea-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.recorded-feedback-modal {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="textarea-container">
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Record Feedback" role="button" class="recorded-feedback-modal" href="#">Link</a>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" spellcheck="false"></textarea>      
    </div>

    <p>Test Content</p>
    <p>Test Content</p>
    <p>Test Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLy8fst1/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a new div and put `a` and `textarea` in that div.

```css
.txtArea {
  position: relative
}
.recorded-feedback-modal {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">


<div class="txtArea">
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Record Feedback" role="button" class="recorded-feedback-modal">Link</a>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
</div>

<p>Test Content</p>
<p>Test Content</p>
<p>Test Content</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. How can I make link follow horizontally if textarea resized?